# Is there a good way to return a string value after a process finishes running?

Tags: windows, process

I have 2 processes, one is A and the other is B. 
A will launch B and wait for B. After B finishes, it will generate a string value. 
How does A get this string value?

platform is windows. 
what I can think about is using registry, or a file. And API GetExitCodeProcess can only get exit code. 
Is there any other better way?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many Windows IPC resources.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28VS.85%29.aspx

You can write the string to stdout and get it with an unnamed pipe:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Get process B to write to `stdout` which can then be read by process A.